# Electron App not working properly, Console says 'require not defined'

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

I just wrote a small app that converts markdown to HTML automatically, but when I type in the text to convert, nothing happens. This is not the first time I am having this problem, an App I did previously for saving bookmarks would not activate some buttons.

Here is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Please see - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - for us to help you effectively, we need to see what you have so far so we can reproduce / fix it.

Comment: Just to add, see: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/17241 - I assume you need to add the nodeIntegration: true - i.e: const w = new BrowserWindow({
webPreferences: {
nodeIntegration: true
}
})

Comment: Thank you, it's working properly!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer my friend. Hopefully you can accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
const w = new BrowserWindow({ webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: true } })
```

The issue can be further explored here:

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/17241

Essentially, the 'nodeIntegration' used to default to true. However the was introduced as a 'Breaking change' when moving to v5